# How to integrate externial js file into Angular 6. Specifically Angular plasmid into Angular 6

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, typescript, angular6

Angular plasmid is a open source angularjs lib. You can see their website http://angularplasmid.vixis.com/download.php

Essentially I first downloaded the angularplasmid.min.js, and added it to my assets folder.

I went to angular.json and imported it js file into scripts

```
"scripts": [
            "src/assets/angularplasmid.complete.min.js"

            ]
```

In my user.component.ts file I declared this js file:

```
declare var angularplasmid: any;
```

And in my user.component.html file I tested the html tag

```
<script src='../../assets/angularplasmid.complete.min.js'></script>

<plasmid sequencelength='1000'></plasmid>
```

This isnt working, I dont properly know how to integrate this js file into angular6.

The error Im getting is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPwn7.png)

Any help is appreciated. I havent imported anything in app.component.ts, I havent done anything else.

Lemme know if you need to see something else, I am a beginner at angular so please dont be harsh at me for being utterly stupid, thank you in advance.

Comment: You are trying to import angular 1 lib into angular 6 application. This won't be a straight forward thing but you can go through below article https://medium.com/@juliapassynkova/enterprise-angular-1-libs-in-angular-2-app-9de6600bbc87

Comment: Awesome Raj, I'll try that out, a million thanks if this works.